# Passing temporary object as parameter by value - is copy constructor called?

Tags: c++, constructor

If a have a class with both standard and copy constructors

```
class Ex{
       //constructor definitions
}
```

and a function that takes it as an argument (by value)

```
void F(Ex _exin){...}
```

take the following piece of code:

```
Ex A;
F(A);   //F's parameter is copy constructed from A
F(Ex());  //F's parameter uses the default constructor
```

In the third line I'm passing to *F* a new (temporary) object of the *Ex* class using the default constructor. My question is: after this new object is created is it also copy constructed/assigned (like it happens in the second line) or is it directly created "inside" *F*?

Comment: I edited my answer, you might find it useful.

Comment: [Don't Be Afraid to Use The Science](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/).  This is trivial to test with a debugger breakpoint or a print inside the constructors.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt not all compilers are standard-compliant. What happens in one compiler on one platform doesn't make a rule. Rules are made by the standard. A compiler can choose to print or not print. Read my answer for further info.

Comment: I agree, @Luchian.  Hence my suggestion that the only way to know for sure how it behaves in *your* environment is to run a test.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt, yes but then it would be a mistake to assume that it will be like that in all environments. That's why people care about the standard.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt even running a test on his environment would be unconclusive, unless it's specified in the compiler documentation. You can't guarantee it will behave the same way every time, even on the same environment, unless you do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was hard to find, but honestly it was bugging me. This is called copy constructor elision.

The standard illustrates this example:

```
class X{
public:
   X(int);
   X(const X&);
   ~X()
};

X f(X);

void g()
{
   X a(1);
   X b = f(X(2)); //identical to what you have:
   a = f(a);
}
```

And it states:

> 12.2/2 Temporary objects
>
> Here, an implementation might use a temporary in which to construct
>   X(2) before passing it to f() using X's copy-constructor;
>   alternatively, X(2) might be constructed in the space used to hold the
>   argument. /.../

After this the standard explains return value optimization, which is basically the same thing.

So it actually has nothing to do with observed behavior, it is up to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

it should call the constructor and the copy-constructor

optimizers could delete unnecessary copying